# How do I print a SOAP request message?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf, soap-client

How do I print a SOAP request message sent to a webservice (CXF2)? I'm using Eclipse.

I want to see which fields it contains and build a SOAP message following this structure.

Comment: Is the message in SOAPMessage object?

Answer (score 0):

You just nedd to add a LoggingInterceptor : see [cxf documentation](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/debugging-and-logging.html)

```
Object implementor = new GreeterImpl();
EndpointImpl ep = (EndpointImpl) Endpoint.publish("http://localhost/service", implementor);

ep.getServer().getEndpoint().getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor());
ep.getServer().getEndpoint().getOutInterceptors().add(new LoggingOutInterceptor())
```

Or if you use [Springframework](http://www.springsource.org/)

```
<bean id="quickFactory" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="serviceClass" value="com.misc.PortType"/>
    <property name="address" value="${service.url}"/>
    <property name="inInterceptors">
        <bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor"/>
    </property>
    <property name="outInterceptors">
        <bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```